# Custom NSObject iniWithCoder not called

Tags: ios, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding, nskeyedunarchiver

I have a custom object, `LevelContent`, which contains some properties. `LevelContent`conforms to `NSCoding`, and I have implemented `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` methods. I save and fetch the data to Parse.com. Saving works fine like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.currentLevelContent];
```

When I fetch the data, I get the `NSData`correctly, but when I try to initialize the `LevelContent`with the downloaded data, `initWithCoder:` never gets called. I try to load the `LevelContent` with this:

```
LevelContent *content = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Here is the code for encoding/decoding

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.tiles forKey:@"tiles"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.attributes forKey:@"attributes"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.level forKey:@"level"];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self == [super init]) {
        self.tiles = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self.tiles addObjectsFromArray:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tiles"]];
        self.attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [self.attributes addEntriesFromDictionary:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"attributes"]];
        self.level = [Level levelWithTopIndex:0 detailIndex:0];
        self.level = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"level"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `if (self == [super init])` to `if (self = [super init])` in `initWithCoder:`

Try this,

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        .....
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. InitWithCoder: still won't get called.

Comment: Check with putting a breakpoint or log in `initWithCoder:` to ensure that it won't get called.

Comment: I have breakpoint placed in the initWithCoder: method and I have confirmed that it's not fired

Comment: Are you sure the `data` is not nil?

Comment: Yes, printing `data` gives out 135 bytes, the same when printing in the save method

Comment: Any logs in console after executing `unarchiveObjectWithData:data`?